# Equivalence Between Global and Local Conditional Independences in Bayesian Networks

Tags: self-study, bayesian-network

The set of local independences assertions given a bayesian network structure $G$ is given as:

$$
I_l(G) = {\forall X_i: (X_i \perp Nd_{X_i} | Pa^{G}_{X_i})}
$$

- $ Nd_{X_i}^G$ represents the non-descendants of $X_i$ in $G$
- $Pa^{G}_{X_i}$ represents the parents of $X_i$ in $G$

The set of global independences given a bayesian network $G$ is given as:

$I(G) = \{
\mathbf{X} \perp\mathbf{Y}|\mathbf{Z}) : \text{d-sep}_{G}(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y}|\mathbf{Z})\}$

- $\text{d-sep}_{G}(\mathbf{X},\mathbf{Y}|\mathbf{Z})\}$ means there is no active trail between $\mathbf{X}$ and $\mathbf{Y}$

Coming from the set of global independences, we can easily arrive in the set of locals:

- For every node $X$, define $Z$ as its parents.
- Assuming the graph is connected, there trail of every non-descendant of $X$ to $X$
- The end of the trail is either $X_k\rightarrow Pa_x \rightarrow X$ or $X_k\leftarrow Pa_x \rightarrow X$, cases in which $X$ and $Y$ are D-separated, and thus, conditionally independent given the set of global independences.

My question lays in how to get from the locals independences to the global.

Daphne's method is to prove how influence doesn't flow in the cases of triples:

- $A \rightarrow B\rightarrow C$, $A\perp C | B$
- $A \leftarrow  B \leftarrow C$, $A\perp C | B$
- $A \leftarrow  B \rightarrow C$, $A\perp C | B$
- $A \rightarrow  B \leftarrow C$, $A\perp C$

However, i'm not satisfied with the intuition behind, and would like the proof that this implies the global dependencies (maybe its stupid, but i'm not getting the catch). Also, does this means that $I(G) = I_l(G)$

Comment: This problem seems intractable in the general case.

Comment: I think it is not Dave, latter in the book it is assumed she has proven it, although she has only provided an intuition.

Comment: You mean Koller's book? OK, she certainly knows what she's talking about but I understand your desire for a complete proof...